# Form: Best way to add multiple items from an autocomplete search, then add attributes to each one

Tags: forms, multi-selection

I have a request to modify this form to allow our customer service folks to specify the dosage (e.g. 1 scoop) and frequency (e.g. once a day) of selected products. 
[image: Add Recommendation Form before]

I'd like to keep the form as standard as I can...is this a good option or am I not thinking something that would be better? It is a bit strange to have the chips that are created put underneath the field in one case and in the field in all others.

[image: Add Recommendation Form after]

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely refrain from having the long products-input that stays empty. It is confusing and clutters the layout.

How about a vertical layout? This would allow you to get rid off the long empty Input field and the repeating labels. Once a product is selected the chip is added above the input field and the input field moves down to make room for the chip and the dosage/frequency input fields.

[image]